# How do i check whether an Array Field is existing or not?

Tags: javascript, java

In JS it would be the following code:

```
if (array[x] != undefined && array[x][y] != undefined) {
    array[x][y] = "foo";
}
```

Is there any possible way that is as simple as this one for Java?
I already tried to check whether the field is null or not, but that doesnt work. Also the undefined looks like not working at all in java

Comment: Java arrays have a `length` property. I would start with that.

Comment: What do you mean by consistent? There is nothing like undefined in java.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should test the length of the array:

```
if (x < array.length && y < array[x].length) {
    array[x][y] = "foo";
}
```

Add a test for `x` and `y` being `> 0` if it's going to be a problem too.